# Storing database settings outside app.config

Tags: c#, app-config, application-settings

I've been writing a c# exe that will be running on a live web server, but I want to be able to test it on our staging server. Since the staging server has different database settings (in the app.config) from my localhost, is there any way I can store the connection string outside the app.config so that I can easily get to it?

Also, is it possible to store the database connection string, then access it via the app.config? This might sound odd, but I'm using a dll from a CMS that uses the value in the .config file.

Comment: Why not have different app.config files for each environment?  That's essentially the point of a configuration file, to provide the settings needed for that environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "externalize" any .NET config section into a separate file, and reference it from `app.config`.

So in your case, you would have something like this in `app.config`:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionstrings.dev.config" />
```

and then create separate configs for e.g. DEV, TEST, PROD environments, with different names. Their content would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>
   -- your connection string here, as normal
</connectionStrings>
```

You can any any number of those separate files, and switching only means changing a single line in your main `app.config` to reference the appropriate external `connectionstrings.ABC.config` file.

Comment: Ok, so I've got my app.config with the configuration settings pointing to another file. Is it possible to change the app.config on each machine that I'm running it on without re-building the app once for each machine?

Answer (score 4):

How about using different app.config in each location?

Comment: Is it possible to store the app.config outside the .exe? When I've done my build (TFS) there doesn't seem to be an app.config in the same way there is with web.config

Comment: This is what I usually do. To avoid mistakes, maintain both config files in source control, using different names and in a location outside of what you're deploying, and make it so that your deployment script automatically installs the correct one as part of the update process.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that, how about creating database settings in `app.config` with prefixes, such as `DevConnectionString` and `ProdConnectionString`. Then, create one more `app.config` element that tells you which environment you're in.

During development, that environment setting is "Dev".
When you deploy your code, change the environment element in `app.config` to "Prod".

When you want to retrieve the database settings in code, you first examine the environment value, and then choose the database settings accordingly.

One variation on this theme is to create an environment variable in Windows on each machine, and interrogate that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it where you want: In a textfile, in an environment variable, pass it as a command line argument.

You just have to write code to read the connection string and pass it to your dataaccess.

When you tell us how you access you database, i can show you how to pass the connectionstring.

But maybe its better to use different configurationfiles per environment.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are using it. It's just a string, so basically you can store it anywhere you like, but if you are using some library that expects the connection string to be in app.config, you would have to find a different way of supplying the string to it.

The `app.config` file is however easy to get to. It's just a text file in XML format, so you can edit using any text editor, like Notepad for example. It's not named `app.config` once it's deployed though, it gets it's filename from the name of the application, with the extension `.config`.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll you own config for connection strings, call it in appropriate to the current environment, e.g. dev.config, qa.config, prod.config, etc and keep it's name into App.config.

In addition, you can add a record to Machine.config, e.g. called Environment and consider it on reading App.config to determine environment config, i.e:

Machine.config:

```
<environment name="Dev" />
```

App.config:

```
<environments>
    <environment name="Dev" config="dev.config" />
    <environment name="QA" config="qa.config" />
    ...
</environments>
```