# app.config - where should it go?

Tags: c#, app-config

This is a follow on from here: [Storing database settings outside app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555550/storing-database-settings-outside-app-config)

So I know it's possible to have one app.config, with different sections externalised, all with different values. But are they like the web.config files in asp.net projects where you can just copy it into the same folder as the rest of the files and it will work, or do I need to compile it in somewhere.

Also, won't it be overwritten by the .exe.config file?

**Edit**

Ok, so I worded this question a bit badly. I've updated it.

Comment: Your resulting `MyApp.exe.config` **will** be recreated on every build - but **not** your externalized configs (unless you specifically do something to achieve this yourself, in your build process)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Winforms or console apps only have **one** config - it's called `app.config` in your project, and will be renamed to `YourApplication.exe.config` by Visual Studio when building the app.

Winforms and console apps do not feature the same kind of "hierarchical" configuration like web applications do.

You can externalize certain config sections into separate configs that will be merged in by means of the `configSource=` attribute which is available on every configuration section, but that's about as far as it goes.

If you have your `app.config` referencing other external config's for certain config sections, then your `MyApp.exe.config` will be re-created every time you compile - but the other externalized config's will be left alone (unless you specifically do something to overwrite them, too, in your build process).

You can of course programmatically also load and parse additional config files, but that's entirely up to you and not part of the basic .NET config system.

You should also check out Jon Rista's three-part series on .NET 2.0 configuration up on CodeProject.

- [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Highly recommended, well written and extremely helpful!

Comment: Can I have one app.config per environment?

Comment: @Piers: In Winforms: no, not really. You will have to create one config for each externalized config section for each environment, and then just reference those from your one and only app.config...